# Copy cells from an Excel workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

Hi im new in VBA and im trying to copy content from some cells, to the last column empty espace of other workbook in sequencial order, but the cell where the data is, is disperse through he book,

```
Sub CopyName()
'Copy's selected cell to cell K2 within same worksheet... which then triggers vlookups with additional info

Dim wb As Workbook
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

filePath = "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Lab2.xlsx"
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
Selection.Copy
Range("C6").Select
Range("C7").Select
Range("C8").Select
Range("C9").Select
Range("C10").Select
Worksheets("Hoja2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("C6").Value
Worksheets("Hoja2").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("C7").Value
Worksheets("Hoja2").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("C8").Value
Worksheets("Hoja2").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("C9").Value
Worksheets("Hoja2").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("C10").Value


wb.Open("C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Lab2.xlsx").Worksheets("Series").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("C6").Value
wb.Open("C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Lab2.xlsx").Worksheets("Series").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("C7").Value
'Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Lab2.xlsx").Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("C8").Value
'Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Lab2.xlsx").Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("C9").Value
'Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Lab2.xlsx").Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("C10").Value


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having with this code?  You open `Lab2.xlsx` but then open it twice again ?

Comment: Yeahh that´s was just rubish, i was desperate, I just want that the cell content of Workbook Lab.xlsm be copied in Lab2.xlsx in the last space of given column, But the Info in Lab.xlsm can be in any specified cell, C1,C2,C3... or D1,D2,D3 etc..

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this:

```vb
Sub CopyName()
    'use Const for fixed values
    Const DEST_WB_PATH As String = "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Lab2.xlsx"

    Dim wbSrc As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    
    Set wbSrc = ThisWorkbook 'or some other specific workbook
    Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets("Hoja1")
    
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(DEST_WB_PATH)
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Hoja2")
    
    'populate the next empty row in the destination sheet
    With wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
        .Columns("B").Value = wsSrc.Range("C6").Value
        .Columns("C").Value = wsSrc.Range("C7").Value
        .Columns("D").Value = wsSrc.Range("C8").Value
        .Columns("E").Value = wsSrc.Range("C9").Value
        .Columns("F").Value = wsSrc.Range("C10").Value
    End With
    
    wbDest.Close savechanges:=True

End Sub
```